# How to display a random image from Wikimedia Commons in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Basically I'm trying to use Java to display a random Wikimedia Commons image in a Jframe.

This is the code that I've worked out so far:

```
            URL imageUrl = new URL("https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:"".jpg");
                    //"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Kisselbach_Concerto_350_DLX_organ_01.jpg/800px-Kisselbach_Concerto_350_DLX_organ_01.jpg");
            InputStream in = imageUrl.openStream();
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);
            ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon (img);
            JFrame f = new JFrame("imagesting");
         JPanel MyPanel = new JPanel();
         JLabel label = new JLabel (image2);
           MyPanel.add(label);
         f.getContentPane().add(MyPanel, "Center"); // Paste MyPanel in center
        // of the contentPane    
         f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
          f.setVisible(true);
            in.close();

        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            //log the error
        }
```

The grahic part works just fien with a normal image URL.The problem is that I don't know how to get the code to load the image URL that results from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File instead of the link itself.Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are asking for a very specific page, you might get away with knowing how the page is returned.  You are always going to have to rely on some assumptions about the page returned to determine which image on the page is the one you actually want.  As such this solution could be fragile - if Wikimedia changes significantly it will fail:

```
public class ShowRandomImage {
    private static String RANDOM_IMG_URL = "https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(RANDOM_IMG_URL);
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            in.lines().flatMap(s -> {
                int i = s.indexOf("<img ");
                if (i >= 0) {
                    int j = s.indexOf("src=\"");
                    if (j > 0) {
                        int k = s.indexOf('"', j+5);
                        if (k > 0) {
                            return Stream.of(s.substring(j+5,k));
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }).findFirst().ifPresent(ShowRandomImage::handleImage);
        }
    }

    private static void handleImage(String url) {
        System.out.println(url);
        try {
            URL imgUrl = new URL(url);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Random Image");
            frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imgUrl)));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Something went wrong fetching the image: "+ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The primary assumption here is that the first image in the returned HTML is the one we want.  That happens to be the case at the time I wrote this.

Comment: This gives me the following errors:- The method readAllBytes() is undefined for the type InputStream (line:23), Main cannot be resolved(line 37) and - The method lines() is undefined for the type String (line 25).

Comment: @GiuliustheWizard That example was written with Java 12.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but I'm still getting the " Main cannot be resolved" error and I can't find any way to solve it. What should I do?

Comment: You should look at the error message and recognize my obvious typo ;-) Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to embed the entire page, as far as Swing’s builtin parser understands it, e.g.

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Example");
f.setContentPane(new JEditorPane("https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File"));
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
f.setVisible(true);
```

Extracting the actual image URL is a bit more involved, but we can utilize the builtin parser:

```
URL url = new URL("https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File");
URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
String enc = c.getContentEncoding();
if(enc == null) {
    enc = new DataFlavor(c.getContentType()).getParameter("charset");
    if(enc == null) enc = "UTF-8";
}
List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();
((HTMLDocument)new HTMLEditorKit().createDefaultDocument()).getParser()
    .parse(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream(), enc),
    new HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void handleSimpleTag(HTML.Tag t, MutableAttributeSet a, int pos) {
            if(t == HTML.Tag.IMG)
                images.add(a.getAttribute(HTML.getAttributeKey("src")).toString());
        }
    }, true);

JFrame f = new JFrame("Example");
// have no heuristic which image to use, but currently, it's the first one
f.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL(images.get(0)))));
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
f.setVisible(true);
```